# Docker_connection curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose

I am trying to create docker for my angular application,
docker file

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and yarn.lock to the container
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Expose the desired port
EXPOSE 4205
# EXPOSE 80
RUN yarn start

# Start the frontend application
# CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

and Docker-compose file is

```
version: '3'

services:
  www-sdk:
    build:
      context: /root/Documents/frontend/www-sdk
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/cert/client
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    ports:
      - 4205:4205
    networks:
      - journey
    
  www-sdk-1:
    build:
      context: /root/Documents/frontend/www-sdk
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/cert/client
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    ports:
      - 4206:4205
    networks:
      - journey

  www-sdk-2:
    build:
      context: /root/Documents/frontend/www-sdk
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/cert/client
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    ports:
      - 4207:4205
    networks:
      - journey

networks:
  journey:
```

now when my I can access the port 4205 inside docker using curl but outside the docker I get error : **curl http://localhost:4205
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer**

I tried to do it directly with port mapping -p 4205:4205 still not work.